# Scala Parallel Collections: How to know and configure the number of threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing

I am using scala parallel collections.

```
val largeList = list.par.map(x => largeComputation(x)).toList
```

It is blazing fast, but I have a feeling that I may run into out-of-memory issues if we run too may "largeComputation" in parallel.

Therefore when testing, I would like to know how many threads is the parallel collection using and if-need-be, how can I configure the number of threads for the parallel collections.

Comment: Did you read this piece of [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance)? In particular the section "How big should a collection be to go parallel?"

Comment: I saw it, but it wasn't clear to me what are they doing. I know we need to do something with the ForkJoinTaskSupport thing... but what exactly is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of scaladoc where they explain how to change the task support and wrap inside it the `ForkJoinPool`. When you instantiate the `ForkJoinPool` you pass as the parameter desired parallelism level:

```
Here is a way to change the task support of a parallel collection:

import scala.collection.parallel._
val pc = mutable.ParArray(1, 2, 3)
pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2))
```

So for your case it will be

```
val largeList = list.par
largerList.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
  new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(x)
)
largerList.map(x => largeComputation(x)).toList
```